# String XML to JSON conversion in .NET without using XmlDocument

Tags: json, multithreading, performance, xmldocument, domparser

I'm trying to find a more memory efficient solution for converting XML string to JSON string (and vice versa)
without using **XmlDocument**.

Currently, all 3rd party libraries i tried, expects XmlDocument as input.

Before I'm writing my own parser using **XmlReader**, i was wondering if anyone know of a out of the box solution?

Comment: What libraries have you tried?  Do any of them accept an XmlReader?

Comment: fastJSON & serviceStack do not support xml to json parsing. Newton's JSON.Net do support it but uses XmlDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own thin **LightXmlDocument** which holds a tree of objects representing xml elements.

**LoadXml** method implemented using **XmlReader**, i'm reading the xml string and building the tree.

Tested with 10 threads each thread iterating 900 times over different xml sizes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly: Generate JSON directly from XML or deserialize the XML string to an object and then serialize it to JSON?

If you need a `XmlSerializer` take a look into this one I created (it uses `XmlReader` internally), you can find the code and how to use it here:

[XML serialization using Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233908/Xml-serialization-using-generics)

Comment: Directly from XML string to JSON string. Something similar to: [http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm](http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm)